# How to set a .page to be an index page/home page on a subfolder

Tags: teamsite, interwoven

I am wondering if it's possible to set an index/home page in a subfolder.

So for example if I were to go to path site.com/subfolder/ my home.page would load automatically instead of having to type site.com/subfolder/home.page

Thank you for advice/help

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible if you front load a Web server to handle all incoming request. Add a URL handled to RewriteRule all request to /foldername/ to /foldername/index.page /foldername/home.page

---

Similar to Apache rule below.

RewriteRule   ^/(puppies|canines)/(.*)    /dogs/$2  [R]

RewriteRule   ^/(.*)/    /$1/index.page  [R]
RewriteRule   ^/(.*)/    /$1/home.page  [R]

Comment: Will this only apply to puppies, canines and dogs folder? Is there a way to make this work on any subfolder?